# Insert distinct values into table with IDs

Tags: sql-server, insert, initialization

Let's say I have the following table:

```
camp_1, camp_2
0, 048
00, 048
000, 042
000, 043
```

I now want to insert these values into a new table dim_promotion, which should look like this:

```
PromotionID, CampaignID, CouponID
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 1,
3, 3, 2,
4, 3, 3
```

I know how I can fill the tables (dim_campaigns and dim_coupons which stand behind CampaignID and CouponID) by doing this:

```
    INSERT INTO [REPORTING].dbo.dim_campaigns
SELECT DISTINCT
camp_2  AS CampaignID
FROM [reporting2].[dbo].[reporting_rawdata_v2]
```

The primary keys for the respective three tables (dim_coupons, dim_campaigns and dim_promotion) are all set to "Identity Specification = YES"

So how do I then fill dim_promotion? What is the natural order? FIrst derive dim_campaigns and dim_coupons and then isnert this into dim_promotion or the other way round?

EDIT: I have the following DB model (only an excerpt) I am only referring to the yellow fields.

RIght now, we have only large table (rawdatatbl) where all data is stored (CampaignCode, CouponCode, Campaign Name, CouponName). This is not really efficient and that's why I want to compeltely restructure the model (see the screenshot). So, as currently the data does not consist of any IDs at all, I do need IDs to fill the new tables dim_campaigns and dim_coupons. This means: To fill dim_campaigns I would run a SELECT DISTINCT campaign_code on my current rawdatatbl and then Insert this into dim_campaigns (CampaignID is automatically filled by using auto_increment and CampaignName is filled with 'Dummy'). The same I could do for dim_coupons. But how can I then use this data to initialize the Dim_promotion table? Or what is the best process to transform my current data from rawdatatbl into IDs?
[image]

Comment: I do not get the logic of the data you want to insert... Please explain some details (about the underlying tables and business rules)

Comment: Your question is vague. please shed some light into it by providing the table structures. anyway, if your problem is *identity* specification of some columns, you can temporary disable this feature by `SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_name ON;`

Comment: I have edited my initial question. It is really difficult to explain for me

Answer (score 0):

one possible way is :-

```
---- insert your all distinct Campaign data 
Insert Into dim_campaigns(CampaignCode,CampaignName)
Select  Distinct
         cm.CampaignCode
        ,cm.CampaignName
From    rawdatatbl As cm

---- insert your all distinct Coupon data 
Insert Into dim_coupons(CouponCode,CouponName)
Select  Distinct
         c.CouponCode
        ,c.CouponName
From    rawdatatbl As c


Declare  @Total             Int
        ,@Inc               Int
        ,@RowId             Int
        ,@CampaignCode      Varchar(100)
        ,@CouponCode        Varchar(100)

        ----Primary keys
        ,@CampaignId        Int
        ,@CouponId          Int
        ,@PromotionID       Int



Select   @CampaignCode = ''
        ,@CouponCode = ''

----loop through one by one and take necessary action
Select   @Total = Count(1)
        ,@Inc = 0
        ,@RowId = 0
From    rawdatatbl As c With (Nolock)

While (@Inc < @Total)
Begin
    Select  Top 1
             @RowId = [TableUniqueId]
            ,@CampaignCode = c.CampaignCode
            ,@CouponCode = c.CouponCode
            ---- others columns
    From    rawdatatbl As c
    Where   [TableUniqueId] > @RowId
    Order By [TableUniqueId] Asc

    Select  @CampaignId = dc.CampaignId
    From    dim_campaigns As dc
    Where   dc.CampaignCode = @CampaignCode

    Select  @CouponId = dc.CouponId
    From    dim_coupons As dc
    Where   dc.CouponCode = @CouponCode

    If (@CampaignId > 0 And @CouponId > 0)
    Begin
        Insert Into dim_promotion(CampaignID,CouponID)
        Select  @CampaignId,@CouponId

        Select  @PromotionID = @@Identity

        ---- other operation insert/update based on @PromotionID you can do here.
    End


    Select   @Inc = @Inc + 1
            ,@CampaignCode = ''
            ,@CouponCode = ''
            ,@CampaignId = 0
            ,@CouponId = 0
End
```